# how do I pull to a bare repository?

Tags: git

I have a "main" bare repository and a "personal" bare repository. I want to update changes form "main" to "personal", so I run:

```
$ git pull
fatal: /home/gimenero/applib/git/libexec/git-core/git-pull cannot be used without a working tree.
```

How do I pull the changes pushed to "main"?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

A `git pull` does a `fetch` followed by a `merge`, and you can't merge without a working tree. (There would be nowhere to resolve merge conflicts if they should arise.)

Instead, you could just fetch. Assuming your main repository is configured as a remote called origin on your personal repository:

```
$ git fetch origin master:master
```

Note that this will only be successful if the master branch of your personal repository is mirroring the master branch of the main repository. Otherwise, Git will reject the non-fast-forward fetch.

Comment: I think you mean git fetch origin master:master

Comment: Yeah, I thought fetch did it, but when I wrote: 
"git fetch" it says: "From /home/rater/gitRepo/src * branch            HEAD -> FETCH_HEAD". That 'HEAD->FETCH_HEAD' confused me. What does it mean? (It looks as if it fetches to a FETCH_HEAD for later merging like in a non-bare repo).

Comment: when I write: "git fetch origin master:master" it doesn't say anything.

Comment: I don't understand. If I fetch my local master branch pointer wouldn't point to the same commit of the remote master pointer. How can it fast forward, wasn't that suppose to only happen during a pull?

Comment: I thought `git fetch --all` would work but it did not give the desired result (i.e. if you do `git fetch --all` in the bare "personal" repo, then cd into the non-bare "personal" repo and do a `git pull` none of the changes from the master repo are pulled)

Comment: Thanks it works, I would like to execute few commands after this, Is there any hooks available for it or by any other option.

Answer (score 49):

Update with:

```
$ git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* --prune
```

### What does this do?

First an aside:  When we speak of a branch named "xyz", git actually addresses it as `refs/heads/xyz`.  But you can type "`xyz`" for short because otherwise it would be insane.  (Incidentally, tags are `refs/tags/xyz`.)  Plain `xyz` is ambiguous as it could be a branch, a tag, or the first N letters of a commit hash.  `refs/heads/xyz` on the other hand explicitly represents a branch.

So even though you can type `git fetch origin foo:bar` to grab their `foo` branch as named `bar` in your repository, you can more explicitly type `git fetch origin refs/heads/foo:refs/heads/bar` to do the same thing.  (Although if `foo` was actually a tag and not a branch, the latter will fail because their `refs/heads/foo` doesn't exist.  Explicitness ftw.)

`git fetch origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` means *all their branch are belong to us*.  The command is run as if the `*` part is substituted to their branch name for each of their branches. i.e. `git fetch origin refs/heads/abc:refs/heads/abc refs/heads/def:refs/heads/def ...` (assuming they have branches named `abc` and `def`).

The `--prune` option means any branches we have in our repository that matches `refs/heads/*` but doesn't exist in their repository are *deleted*.

Finally, the `+` prefix is to allow non-fast-forward fetches.  Without it, any update to branches that require *force-updates* are rejected.

Put together, the end result is that branches in your repository ends up looking exactly the same as theirs.

### Here's an example output:

```
 - [deleted]               (none)     -> bar
 * [new branch]            foo        -> foo
   4812558a5f..a6aeec6517  abc        -> abc
 + a1b2c3d4e5...1a2b3c4d5e def        -> def  (forced update)
```

- The example tells us they have branches `foo`, `abc`, `def` while we have (had) one extra: `bar`
- Notice the deletion of `bar` by `--prune` and force update of `def` allowed by the `+` prefix.

Here's what happens instead if `+` and `--prune` were left off:

```
 * [new branch]            foo        -> foo
   4812558a5f..a6aeec6517  abc        -> abc
 ! [rejected]              def        -> def  (non-fast-forward)
```

### One last thing:

Compare the command at the top with the following:

```
$ git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* [--prune]
```

This is essentially what happens when we type `git fetch origin [--prune]`!

Comment: The answer above may be more powerful and flexible than the other, but it's not visible.  With a little explanation this answer could be much more interesting. What I understand is that this command is the reverse of a git `push --mirror`, which is dangerous (replaces even in case of conflicts, removes on destination anything that is not on sender side).