# How do I pull/fetch with Git *INTO* a bare repository?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

I'm writing a tool to backup all my repositories from [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) (which supports Git and Mercurial) to my local machine.

It already works for Mercurial, where I do it like this:

- create a new empty repository without a working copy on the local machine
  (the same like a `bare` Git repository)
- pull from the remote repository into the local empty repository

Now I'm trying to do the same with Git.

I [already found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274697/how-do-i-pull-to-a-bare-repository) that I can't directly `pull` to a bare repository and that I should use `fetch` instead.

So I tried it:

```
C:\test>git fetch https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net.git
remote: Counting objects: 1255, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1178/1178), done.
remote: Total 1255 (delta 593), reused 717 (delta 56)
Receiving objects: 100% (1255/1255), 13.66 MiB | 706 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (593/593), done.
From https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Obviously Git **did** fetch something, but the local repository is empty after that.
(`git log` says `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`)

What am I doing wrong?

**Disclaimer:**
I have only very, very basic Git knowledge (I usually use Mercurial).
And I'm using Windows, if that matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git log and show on a bare repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214711/git-log-and-show-on-a-bare-repo)

Comment: @CharlesB: None of the answers in this link work for me. Not even things like `git branch -va` that worked for the asker, not the suggested `git log branchname` (I tried `master`), nor the "To visualize everything in the repository..." command at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
git fetch https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net.git master:master
```

Comment: This only seems to fetch the master branch (I just tried it with https://github.com/dontangg/nocco, because Dapper has no other branches). Is it possible to fetch **all** branches? This will be a backup tool, and of course I want to back up everything that is there.

Comment: Something like `"*:*"` or `"refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"` should do.

Comment: `*:*` doesn't work for me (`fatal: Invalid refspec '*.*'`), but `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` does the trick. Thank you!

Comment: I think it depends on git version, then.

Comment: Do you know a link where the differences between the Git versions are explained? It worked on a machine with Git 1.7.7, but the machine I'm using now has Git 1.6.5.1, and I can't get `fetch` to work at all. I'd really like to see a reference that tells me which command works with which Git version. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know of a better resource for this information than git itself: http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git/tree/HEAD:/Documentation/RelNotes

Comment: Note, that the edit by @FirstZero doesn't fully apply to the *bare* repository.

Comment: I needed this for a bare repo used for redmine setup `git fetch origin *:*` in crontab did the trick

Answer (score 17):

To backup the remote repository into your bare repository regulary configure first

```
git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net.git
git config remote.origin.fetch "+*:*"
```

and then simply run

```
git fetch --prune
```

to backup.

- You probably can skip the fist configuration addition as this should has been already set while cloning the remote repository.
- Please also mind the enclosing double quotation marks (`"`) in the above command to protect the asterix (`*`) not to be interpreted from your shell.
- The plus sign is needed to allow non-fastforward updates. That is probably your intention if you want to backup the current state of your remote.
- Option `--prune` is used to also delete by now non-existent branches.

Comment: A good explanation with all the pertinent facts in one place, especially useful is the point about double-quotes and the need for the `+` prefixing the [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).

Answer (score 4):

I think you if you really want to backup. You can try `$ git clone --mirror XXXX` command. it will get almost everything from repository. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Yes, but I want the backup to run regularly. So after the first run, the local repository already exists --> I have to run `pull`/`fetch`/whatever anyway and make sure that this pulls **everything** as well.

Comment: After you mirrored you bare. you can use 'git fetch --all --progress -v' to update your local bares.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ git fetch https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net.git +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* --prune
```