# How to move git repositories from github to local server running gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite

I would like to know the preferable way to move all my git repositories currently hosted on github to a new git server gitolite-based.

Just for knowing, the reason why I'm  doing this switch is the adoption of Redmine to support our project management process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the new repo in gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf

```
repo my-new-repo
    RW+            = your-user
```

Add, commit and push the changes into gitolite-admin

```
git add conf/gitolite.conf
git commit -m "Added my-new-repo"
git push origin
```

Clone your github repo and checkout all the branches present

```
git clone github.com:/USERNAME/YOUR_REPO.git
cd YOUR_REPO
for branch in `git branch -a | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master`; do     git branch --track ${branch##*/} $branch; done
```

Remove the github remote, and add your gitolite remote:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin YOURSERVER:my-new-repo.git
```

Push all the refs onto the repo managed by gitolite:

```
git push --all origin
```

I verified the steps in a test repository of mine, and all the refs seem to have propagated into the new repo.

**UPDATE:** Like Seth pointed out, any other refs other than branches are not propagated to the new repo. I too feel **Mirror** would be a better option.

Comment: As mentioned in the first comment, --all only works for local refs.  You either need to make all of the remote refs local or use --mirror (one of the few times that --mirror is what you want).

Comment: @SethRobertson - You're right, tags and any other refs other than branches do not get propagated :(

Comment: As suggested, I used the option --mirror when cloning and all the refs were copied.

Answer (score 5):

With reference to this: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/basic-admin/#appendix-1-bringing-existing-repos-into-gitolite. How about:

1. On the gitolite server, make a mirror of the github repositories with the command `git clone --mirror <github git repo path>`
2. Move the mirror repo to the correct location as in the link above, then just follow the section **moving existing repos into gitolite** of the guide?

Comment: @ArjunMehta I think the referenced URL should be http://gitolite.com/gitolite/basic-admin/#appendix-1-bringing-existing-repos-into-gitolite

Comment: @cknoll, reference link had been updated as suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing I can think of would be to pull a local copy, change the origin to the new server, and then push:

```
git pull --all
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <new repo address>
git push --all --repo=origin
```

Comment: This will only push all your refs in the cloned repo (which will be only the branches you've checked out locally). You need to checkout all the refs, and then do a **push --all**

Comment: This is one of the few times that --mirror will actually do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you also want to bring your tags to the new server. This can be done by

```
    git push --tags
```

Answer (score 0):

To mirror a GitHub repo onto Gitolite, first create a new repo on Gitolite (using the `gitolite-admin` repo - I'll assume the Gitolite admin knows how to do that), but here's an example config entry:

```
repo github/<gh-user>/<gh-repo>
desc = "Repository description [https://github.com/<gh-user>/<gh-repo>]"
owner = "My Name"
category = "GitHub"
RW+ = my_key
```

where `<gh-user>` is the GitHub user and `<gh-repo>` is the GitHub repository being mirrored. This example places the mirror within a GitHub and user subdirectory, but you can use any `repo` path that suits.

Then, from anywhere with access to both GitHub and Gitolite:

```
$ git clone --mirror https://github.com/<gh-user>/<gh-repo>
$ cd <gh-repo>.git
$ git push --mirror gitolite git@git:github/<gh-user>/<gh-repo>
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf <gh-repo>.git
```

where `git@git` is the SSH user and hostname used to connect to Gitolite. The local clone is temporary and is deleted afterwards.

The OP asked only about moving repositories, in which case he might stop here. However, should it be desirable to host a local mirror of a repo on GitHub and periodically synchronize the local mirror then here's a way to do that.

To sync the Gitolite mirror with GitHub, log on to the Gitolite server as the Gitolite admin (`git`) user and perfom the following configuration:

```
$ cd ~git/repositories/github/<gh-user>/<gh-repo>
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/<gh-user>/<gh-repo>
$ git config remote.origin.fetch "+*:*"
```

The parameters in the commands are explained clearly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33461528/712506).

Then, to sync the repo:

```
$ git fetch --prune
```

The fetch could be automated via a `cron` job.