# Git clone --bare / fetch

Tags: git

I have a git repository with long and strange history. I don't know what the developers did with this repository and cannot control what they are doing with it now.

But I need to clone this repository (for redmine integration) and fetch all changes periodically.

What do I do:

```
git clone --bare git@git.server.com:/opt/git/repo
cd repo.git
git log
```

Now I can see all commits.  Fine.

Next a developer make a commit in the main repository and I want to fetch all changes (all brances, tags and so on, and so on):

```
> git fetch --all 
Fetching origin
remote: Counting objects: 18, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 14 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (14/14), done.
From git.gmcs.ru:/opt/git/ecco
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

But if a ask the commit history I didn't see that last commit which was made in the main repository.  Why ?

If I post not enough information I am ready to give you all the needed.

Thanks in advance.

**Updated**

Here is a brach information in the original repsitory:

```
git branch -a
  one
  test
* master
  release
```

Here is a branch information in the cloned repository:

```
git branch -a
  one
  test
* master
  release
```

I can see last commits in the master branch of original repository, but can not find them in the master branch of cloned repository.

Comment: `fatal: /usr/lib/git/git-pull` cannot be used without a working tree.  I think it is because it is a bare repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `git pull`

or run `git merge` after fetch to get fetched changes

if you have a bare repository you can not do a pull, because a pull wants to merge with HEAD, which a bare repo does not have.

to update bare repository you can add it as `remote` to non-bare repository and push to it.

But I think `--mirror` instead of `--bare` will work for you as is.

> Compared to --bare, --mirror not only maps local branches of the
>   source to local branches of the target, it maps all refs (including
>   remote branches, notes etc.) and sets up a refspec configuration such
>   that all these refs are overwritten by a git remote update in the
>   target repository.

and then you can use `git remote update` to update mirrored repository

Comment: `fatal: /usr/lib/git/git-pull` cannot be used without a working tree. I think it is because it is a bare repository.

Comment: I'm sorry, could be, do you need to have bare repository?

Comment: Yes, as I see the Redmine require a bare repository.  Moreover, this method works fine with all other repositories, bit I can not figure out what is wrong with this repo.

Answer (score 16):

To fetch more updates into a bare repo, I do:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```

Then I can do:

```
git fetch
```

Comment: This is the best answer. All the other answers to the problem of fetching *into* a repo created by `git clone --bare` do not fix it for me. The symbolic-ref solution is not great because it is necessary to do that for each branch each time, not desirable.

Comment: If you use `git fetch -p` it will additionally prune branches that have been removed from origin.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch into your bare repository regulary configure first

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+*:*"
```

and then simply run

```
git fetch --prune
```

to fetch *all* changes, including tags, new branches and even branch deletions (option `--prune`).

- Please also mind the enclosing double quotation marks (`"`) in the above command to protect the asterix (`*`) not to be interpreted from your shell.
- The plus sign is needed to allow non-fastforward updates. That is probably your intention if you want to backup the current state of your remote.
- Note: Tag deletions are not fetched using this configuration.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/33461528/4138912.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `HEAD` of your bare repository with `git symbolic-ref`, e.g. to point it to branch `master` from remote `origin`

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/remotes/origin/master
```

If you use `git fetch` to update remotes it will update e.g. `origin/master`. All that was missing was to repoint the clone's `HEAD`.

Comment: I have tried it but got: `git log` -> `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`.