# how to fetch only commits history, not files using git

Tags: git, file, repository, clone

is there any way to fetch only history? Sometimes repositories are big and it takes very long period of time to download it.

I don't need a files, i just need to look for commits history with git log and git show.

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch only commits history"? How is this different from what Git does by default? (Consider: If you can look at a repository's history you have the contents of every revision.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No if you want to see all the history locally, you will need to clone *all* changes.
You just can do so in a [bare repo (git `clone --bare`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13453624/6309) in order to not checkout the default branch HEAD.

But that won't mean downloading *less* data: only a shallow clone would download less, but that would mean a partial history.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't.

In Git repositories, commits and files are managed separately. So it should be possible to implement a feature to fetch only commits, but such a feature is not implemented yet.

Note that a commit in a repository includes only information `git show -q <commit>` shows.
So, if such a feature would be implemented, you can't see diffs or so in a repository fetched by the feature.