If there is a way to get commit log information online with out clone the whole repository?
There are many git repositories on my gitlab server, and I want to statistics their commit information. I have to clone every repository and run git log command within the directory. Its very slow and might damage my hard disks if the operations were frequently. So, if there was a way to get commit information online without clone the huge repositories?
I has not found a git command without a local repository and googled nothing for it

Related / possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41198653/, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48852630/, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52916879, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57896644

No such git command yet. If Gitlab apis cannot meet your needs, you can implement your own apis (with Django for example) on the server to send back commit information on request.

It is not possible using git alone, but gitlab has an API you can access. Check the documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitlab-api%5D+commits

If you have SSH access to the remote repository, you can use the git log command with the appropriate options to view commit history directly from the command line without cloning the entire repository. For example:
git ls-remote <repository_url>

This command will list all the references in the remote repository, including branches and commits.

git ls-remote doesn't show log (list of commits); it only shows heads (tips of branches) and tags. As for SSH — the OP runs Gitlab so has Git+SSH access, bit no SSH access to run commands.
