# Git update log of a bare repository

Tags: git, logging, bare

I need to regularly extract the git logs for all branches of several repositories.
While I could clone them and then perform a git fetch, I thought about saving some disk space and time and only cloning them as bare:

`git clone --bare repoUrl`

After the clone, all logs and branches are up to date.
I can issue `git log --all` and I can see all the changes up to the clone moment.

However, I am not able to fetch changes from the remote repo when it gets updated. I.e. if I issue:
`git fetch --all` and then `git log --all`, I don't see any of the change that happened in the remote repo.

How can I update the state of my local repository when the remote receives new commits?

I have tried:

- `git fetch` but it doesn't seem to get any update (i.e. `git log --all` doesn't show any change).
- `git fetch origin master:master` only updates the master branch
- `git branch -r` doesn't show anything
- `git branch -a` shows only the branches available at the moment of the clone
- `git remote -v` shows correctly the url of the remote repository.

Comment: I'm confused, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33461528/8989626) related to a similar question (I only need to extract the logs, not to pull the code).

After cloning, I've to add:

`git config remote.origin.fetch "+*:*"`

so that git can keep track of all the branches, even remote ones.
Then, issuing `git fetch --all --prune` and `git log --all` I can see all the changes.

Answer (score 1):

use `git log --remotes` after `git fetch --all` to get the log for the remote branches.